# Server not responding to http or ping but ssh works

Tags: ssh, vps, httpd, ping

I can access to a VPS through ssh. That VPS has httpd installed on it and running to listen onto port 80. However I can't ping that VPS nor access to his apache but I can log in with ssh.

This is strange because I've also check for IPTables blocks (and even disabled the service).

Since the server isn't mine but of a client of mine, the only scenario that could lead to that issue, to me, is a firewall between the internet and that server. Is this the only explaination, or someone can give me another pointer?

Comment: When you attemp to access the site via ping or http, do you get a timeout or an denied message?

Comment: @dacracot: timeout that let me think about firewall

Comment: Sounds like a firewall.  See if traceroute will give any clues.

Comment: @dacracot Yeah, it seems a firewall issue. I'll contact my client for some extra info next week!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that's the most likely explanation, if the server was on a residential connection, that could cause issues, some ISPs block classic "server" ports, 25, 80, 443, and so forth. Xinetd and other systems which control access to ports could also cause issues. In theory, you could also configure httpd to respond only to specific ports also..

That's my mental list exhausted..

Comment: Thank you for your anwser: I will check with my client and see

Comment: Hope you can get it sorted!

Comment: Hows about an iptables -L

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that ICMP (protocol used by ping) was blocked by firewall, that's why it was unreachable by pinging it from the outside.